# fuselage structure

Tags: aircraft-structures

How can a mechanic measure the distance of underlying structural elements of fuselage skin (e.g. stringers, internal doublers around door cutouts) from a specific cracked fastener hole in the fuselage skin through external inspection, given that SRM schematics don't include all required dimensions?

Is it necessary to recourse to internal inspection subsequent to removing internal interior stuff (side walls, insulation blankets, etc.)?

Comment: Please follow the [instructions here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get the accounts merged.

Comment: the last account is scheduled for deletion

Comment: This sounds like a question for whoever is responsible for the SRM content.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the inspection panels to look inside.
2. Follow the fastener locations.
3. When all else fails, disassemble.